# Count total number of occurrences in pandas dataframe with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe:

```
cat_df.head()

   category depth
0   food    0.0
1   food    1.0
2   sport   1.0
3   food    3.0
4   school  0.0
5   school  0.0
6   school  1.0
...
```

Where `depth = 0` stands for root publication, `depth > 0` are comments.

For each category I want to count the number of root publications (`depth=0`) and number of comments (`depth>0`).

I use `value_counts()` for counting the unique values:

```
cat_df['category'].value_counts().head(15)

category     total number 
food         44062
sport        38004
school       11080
life         8810
...
```

I thought I could put `['depth'] == 0` as a condition inside the dataframe but it didn't work:

```
cat_df[cat_df['depth'] == 0].value_counts().head(5)
```

How do I get the total number of occurences for depth=0 and depth>0?

I want to put it in a table like this:

```
category | total number | depth=0 | depth>0 
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use only one `groupby` for improve performance:

```
df = (cat_df['depth'].ne(0)
                     .groupby(cat_df['category'])
                     .value_counts()
                     .unstack(fill_value=0)
                     .rename(columns={0:'depth=0', 1:'depth>0'})
                     .assign(total=lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
                     .reindex(columns=['total','depth=0','depth>0']))

print (df)
depth     total  depth=0  depth>0
category                         
food          3        1        2
school        3        2        1
sport         1        0        1
```

**Explanation**:

1. First compare `depth` columns by not equal [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) (`!=`)
2. [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by column `category` with [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html)
3. Reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html)
4. `Rename` columns by dictionary
5. Create new `total` column by [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)
6. For custom order of columns add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

EDIT:

```
cat_df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['food', 'food', 'sport', 'food', 'school', 'school', 'school'], 'depth': [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], 'num_of_likes': [10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20]})
```

---

```
print (cat_df)
  category  depth  num_of_likes
0     food    0.0            10
1     food    1.0            10
2    sport    1.0            10
3     food    3.0            20
4   school    0.0            20
5   school    0.0            20
6   school    1.0            20

df = (cat_df['depth'].ne(0)
                     .groupby([cat_df['num_of_likes'], cat_df['category']])
                     .value_counts()
                     .unstack(fill_value=0)
                     .rename(columns={0:'depth=0', 1:'depth>0'})
                     .assign(total=lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
                     .reindex(columns=['total','depth=0','depth>0'])
                     .reset_index()
                     .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)

print (df)
   num_of_likes category  total  depth=0  depth>0
0            10     food      2        1        1
1            10    sport      1        0        1
2            20     food      1        0        1
3            20   school      3        2        1
```

EDIT1:

```
s = cat_df.groupby('category')['num_of_likes'].sum()
print (s)
category
food      40
school    60
sport     10
Name: num_of_likes, dtype: int64

df = (cat_df['depth'].ne(0)
                     .groupby(cat_df['category'])
                     .value_counts()
                     .unstack(fill_value=0)
                     .rename(columns={0:'depth=0', 1:'depth>0'})
                     .assign(total=lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
                     .reindex(columns=['total','depth=0','depth>0'])
                     .reset_index()
                     .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
                     .assign(num_of_likes=lambda x: x['category'].map(s))
)
print (df)
  category  total  depth=0  depth>0  num_of_likes
0     food      3        1        2            40
1   school      3        2        1            60
2    sport      1        0        1            10
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one way using `pandas.concat`:

```
total = df.groupby('category').size()
zero = df[df.depth == 0].groupby('category').size()
nonzero = df[df.depth > 0].groupby('category').size()

res = pd.concat([total, zero, nonzero], axis=1)\
        .rename(columns={0: 'total', 1: 'zero', 2: 'nonzero'})\
        .fillna(0).astype(int)

print(res)

#         total  zero   nonzero
# food        3     1         2
# school      3     2         1
# sport       1     0         1
```

Comment: Thanks. looks like the order of the columns are misleading or the names  confused

Comment: Great answer! I like how your solution is also applicable to non-binary options (when there is more than 0 and non-zero options). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What I will do `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.category,df.depth.ne(0),margins=True).iloc[:-1,:]
Out[618]: 
depth     False  True  All
category                  
food          1     2    3
school        2     1    3
sport         0     1    1
```

If need the name adding rename

```
pd.crosstab(df.category,df.depth.ne(0),margins=True).iloc[:-1,:].rename(columns={True:'depth>0',False:'depth=0'})
```